# Docker exec - Write text to file in container

Tags: bash, docker

I want to write a line of text to a textfile INSIDE a running docker container. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
docker exec -d app_$i eval echo "server.url=$server_url" >> /home/app/.app/app.config
```

Response:

```
/home/user/.app/app.config: No such file or directory
```

Second try:

```
cfg_add="echo 'server.url=$server_url' >> /home/user/.app/app.config"
docker exec -i app_$i eval $cfg_add
```

Response:

```
exec: "eval": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why `-d` for docker exec?

Comment: `eval` is not present in the container. The kernel is shared between the host and the container. The programs are not. If you installed `nc` on your host, the container won't be able to execute it as long as it did not installed it within.

Comment: @Auzias: The issue is not that `eval` is not _present_ in the container (it likely is, as a _shell builtin_ of the container's shell), but that it's _not an external utility_, so `docker exec` can't invoke it.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`eval` is a shell *builtin*, whereas `docker exec` requires an *external utility* to be called, so using `eval` is *not* an option.

Instead, invoke a shell executable in the container (`bash`) *explicitly*, and pass it the command to execute as a *string*, via its  `-c` option:

```
docker exec "app_$i" bash -c "echo 'server.url=$server_url' >> /home/app/.app/app.config"
```

By using a *double-quoted* string to pass to `bash -c`, you ensure that the *current* shell performs string interpolation first, whereas the container's `bash` instance then sees the expanded result as a *literal*, as part of the embedded *single-quoted* string.

---

As for **your symptoms**:

- `/home/user/.app/app.config: No such file or directory` was reported, because the redirection you intended to happen *in the container* actually happened in *your host's shell* - and because dir. `/home/user/.app` apparently doesn't exist in your host's filesystem, the command failed *fundamentally*, *before* your host's shell even attempted to execute the command (`bash` will abort command execution if an output redirection cannot be performed).

  - Thus, even though your first command also contained `eval`, its use didn't surface as a problem until your second command, which actually *did* get executed.
- `exec: "eval": executable file not found in $PATH` happened, because, as stated, `eval` is not an *external utility*, but a *shell builtin*, and `docker exec` can only execute external utilities.

Comment: Here is an example here you can write files with quotes in them. For example you want to write `obj['key'] = 'value'` to a file named `/etc/config.py`


`docker exec "app_$i" bash -c 'echo "obj['"'key'"'] = '"'value '"'"> /etc/config.py'`

Comment: @Gourneau: `"echo \"obj['key'] = 'value'\"> /etc/config.py"` is easier.

Answer (score 25):

Additionally:

If you need to write text from outside the container, this also works:

```
(docker exec -i container sh -c "cat > c.sql") < c.sql
```

This will pipe you input into the container. Of course, this would also work for plain text (no file). It is important to leave off the `-t` parameter.

See https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/9537

UPDATE (in case you just need to copy files, not parts of files):

Docker v17.03 has `docker cp` which copies between the local fs and the container: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/#usage

Answer (score 3):

try to use heredoc:

```
(docker exec -i container sh -c "cat > /test/iplist") << EOF
10.99.154.146
10.99.189.247
10.99.189.250
EOF
```